# How can I deselect non-selected items with an AngularJS ng-click / ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
            <div class="right">
              <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"
                ng-repeat="answer in question.answers"
                ng-click="answer.isSelected = !answer.isSelected">
                {{ answer.letter }}
              </a>
            </div>
```

That's my code. I have many `answers` and I want the user to select one. I have that part working. The part I don't have working is I want to set the `isSelected` for all *other* answers to `false`. How can I accomplish this?

Keep in mind, my data is SUPER nested. So `question` is part of a `ng-repeat="question in instructionSet.questions"` and `instructionSet` is part of another `ng-repeat` and so on.

Comment: something like `ng-click="$parent.question.selectedAnswer = answer"` should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one element you can select, it's better to have one parameter so save the state instead of having it on every object.

```
<div class="right">
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"
        ng-repeat="answer in question.answers"
        ng-click="$parent.question.selectedAnswer =
          $parent.question.selectedAnswer == answer ? null: answer">
        {{ answer.letter }}
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not tested so the `$parent` part could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple - declare a variable above the repeat scope, lets say `selectedIndex` and set it to `-1`

```
$scope.selectedIndex = -1;
```

Now set this to the selected index on click if it's not already, or back to `-1` if it's already selected:

```
ng-click="setIndex($index)">
```

And the method:

```
$scope.setIndex = function(idx) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = $scope.selectedIndex === idx ? -1 : idx;
}
```